# Speed up Redis server inputs

Tags: python, multithreading, redis, multiprocessing

How do speed up this test code in python to Redis on Winxp using python 2.7?
Would multiprocessing be better? The load rate in 6000/s vs publish 100,000/s rates.
I chose 100,000, but could lower in testing. The process takes 15 seconds.

Would changing setting on server help???

```
import time
from time import strftime
import redis
import threading, Queue

start_time = time.time()
cxn = redis.StrictRedis('127.0.0.1',6379,1)


class WorkerMain(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            try: # take a job from the queue            
                row  = self.queue.get_nowait()           
            except Queue.Empty: raise SystemExit

            try:
                cxn.set(row, "Row")
                #print (row, "Row")
            except: print 'Setup Error'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connections =  5

    sml = range(1,100000)    
    queue = Queue.Queue() 
    for row in sml:
        queue.put(str(row))

    threads = []
    for dummy in range(connections):
        t = WorkerMain(queue)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    # wait for all threads to finish
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()


print 
end_time = time.time()
duration = end_time - start_time
print "Duration: %s" % duration
```

Used the code below for mulitprocessing and "monitored" the data with CLI...not all data went into the server.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import redis

start_time = time.time()
cxn = redis.Redis('127.0.0.1',6379,1)

def rset(var):
    cxn.set(var,"value")

if __name__ =='__main__':   
    sml = range(1,10000)
    #for x in sml:print x

    pool = Pool(processes=5)
    for row in sml:
        pool.apply_async(rset, [(row,)])
        #print result.get(), 


end_time = time.time()
duration = end_time - start_time
print "Duration: %s" % duration
```

Here is the pipelined code...... I just commented out the threading stuff.

```
from time import strftime
import redis
import threading, Queue

start_time = time.time()
cxn = redis.StrictRedis('127.0.0.1',6379,0)
pipe = cxn.pipeline(transaction=False)

class WorkerMain(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            try: # take a job from the queue            
                row  = self.queue.get_nowait()           
            except Queue.Empty: raise SystemExit

            try:
                cxn.set(row, "Row")
                #print (row, "ROw")
            except: print 'Setup Error'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #connections =  5

    sml = range(1,100000)    
    #queue = Queue.Queue() 
    for row in sml:
        #queue.put(str(row))
        pipe.set(str(row),"value").execute()# key, value

   # threads = []
   # for dummy in range(connections):
   #     t = WorkerMain(queue)
   #     t.start()
   #     threads.append(t)
   #     
   # # wait for all threads to finish
   # for thread in threads:
   #    thread.join()



print 
end_time = time.time()
duration = end_time - start_time
print "Duration: %s" % duration
```

Comment: USE PIPELINES ~5 times faster. http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/python-redis-py-pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Pipelines. A Pipeline batches commands so you don't pay for network overheads.

See :

1. Section on Pipelines over here https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py
2. Pipelining on Redis.io - http://redis.io/topics/pipelining

Comment: Newbie on Redis....testing! Pipeline wouldnt handle streamed data from doc, would it. I know size today, but what if data is streamed???

Comment: With pipelining, you don't have to know the size/length of data before hand. I'd suggest you take a look at redis-py documentation I linked above. It is really simple to use a pipeline, and it will give you a great speedup.

Comment: I'd recommend testing a single thread/process with pipelining. Also, please paste your pipeline code.

Comment: Looks like you are calling execute on each iteration. Don't do that. You can either keep track of the iteration number and execute every x iterations, or just execute at the end. Essentially what you are doing is telling the pipeline to flush on every command. Kinda defeats the point of pipelining.

Comment: You have to decide how many events you are going to generate, and then batch up inserts using redis pipeline.

Comment: Have a nested loop `while current_time < 3s or count < 50 :`, and then call `execute()` on the pipeline object after the while terminates. You can change the 3s / 50 records depending on the expected volume

Comment: @SripathiKrishnan Pipelineing you can do only when you have a batch of commands to execute. But in several places I use redis to execute only a single command, say retrieve a few fields of a hash key. And this takes ~100-120us. How can I improve this performance?

Answer (score 1):

Using threading for better performance is not a really good idea if you use cpython (the standard python interpreter) because of the gil.

http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

multiprocessing should work better

Comment: MP actually cause dropped data.